# object Object displayed in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, r, opencpu

I'm trying to display the graph plotted by the R function in the opencpu server.
However,it only displays [object Object] in the html page. The following is the code in my AngularJS controller.

```
var req = ocpu.rpc("plotGraph", {
                filepath:"C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.txt"
            }, function(output){
              $("#output").text(output);
            });
```

The following is the R function in the package plotGraph.

```
plotGraph <- function(filepath) {
  test.ecg <- read.table(filepath, quote="\"", comment.char="")
  ecg=ts(test.ecg)
  plot(ecg)

}
```

How do I display the plot created by the R function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `rplot`:

```
var req = $("#output").rplot("plotGraph", {
    filepath:"C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.txt"
});
```

`ocpu.rpc` is to get back json only.

Comment: I have tried it but this appears in the console:OpenCPU error HTTP 400
cannot open the connection

In call:
file(file, "rt")

Comment: It is because R can't read the file. To put data in your opencpu server, either create a connection to a database or save the file as rda in the data folder. See here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will check it out.